# Create a nested parent child list in Java 8

Tags: java, list, java-8, iteration, java-stream

I am new to Java 8 and need a solution to the below problem.

I have two classes as below:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    List<Address> address;
}

class Address {
    String street;
    String city;
    String country;
}
```

Now I have a list coming from database like this:

```
List<Person> findPerson;

adam
26
<123, xyz, yyy>

adam
26
<456, rrr, kkk>

bill
31
<666, uuu, hhh>
```

Now I need to combine the same person objects with different address objects in one, like below?

```
List<Person> findPerson;

adam
26
<123, xyz, 456>
<456, rrr, 123>

bill
31
<666, uuu, 999>
```

How this can be done in Java 8 streams?

Comment: What database are you using? Some databases have enough array support that you can return a sequence type directly from the query. Also, what are the primary and foreign keys on these two tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach, won't require overriding `equals` and `hashCode`:

```
List<Person> merged = findPerson.stream()
    .collect( 
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toMap( 
                (p) -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>( p.getName(), p.getAge() ), 
                Function.identity(), 
                (left, right) -> { 
                    left.getAddress().addAll( right.getAddress() ); 
                    return left; 
                }
            ),        
            ps -> new ArrayList<>( ps.values() ) 
        ) 
    )
;
```

Answer (score 10):

I'd suggest you implement `equals` and `hashcode` in your `Person` class.

Example:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (this == o) return true;
       if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

       Person person = (Person) o;

       if (age != person.age) return false;
       return name != null ? name.equals(person.name) : person.name == null;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
       int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
       result = 31 * result + age;
       return result;
}
```

Then you can have a `Map<Person, List<Address>>` as the receiver type of the result set.

```
Map<Person, List<Address>> resultSet = findPerson.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Function.identity(),
            Collectors.flatMapping(
                p -> p.getAddress().stream(), 
                Collectors.toList()
            )
        )
    )
;
```

This solution utilizes the `flatMapping` collector which is only available as of Java-9.

if you're still on Java-8 then you can do:

```
Map<Person, List<Address>> resultSet = findPerson.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Function.identity(),
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.mapping(
                    Person::getAddress, 
                    Collectors.toList()
                ),
                lists -> lists.stream()
                    .flatMap(List::stream)
                    .collect( Collectors.toList() )
            )
        )
    )   
;
```

*note* - As is, I am currently assuming two or more people are considered equal based on `name` and  `age`, however, if it's only based on `name` or just the `age` then you'll need to tweek the `equals` / `hashcode` methods a little bit.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `Person` implements `hashCode` and `equals` consistently, you could collect to a `Map`:

```
Map<Person, Person> map = findPerson.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        p -> p,
        p -> p,
        (oldPerson, newPerson) -> { 
            oldPerson.getAddress().addAll(newPerson.getAddress()); 
            return oldPerson; 
        }));
```

This uses [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), which works by *merging* a new person with an old person that's already in the map, and by merging we mean adding the addresses.

Now, in the values of the map, you have the merged people:

```
Collection<Person> result = map.values();
```

If you need to return a list:

```
List<Person> result = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

---

**EDIT:**

This assumes that the `List<Address>` of each person is *mutable* (so that `addAll` works). This is not always the case, particularly if you want to not break *encapsulation*, you shouldn't let the addresses of your `Person` objects be modified from outside.

In this case, you could provide a method in `Person` that would be in charged of merging the addresses without breaking encapsulation:

```
public Person merge(Person another) {
    this.address.addAll(another.address);
    return this;
}
```

Or if the list of addresses is immutable:

```
public Person merge(Person another) {
    List<Address> merged = new ArrayList<>(this.address);
    merged.addAll(another.address);
    this.address = merged;
    return this;
}
```

Now the code in the collector can be refactored to:

```
Map<Person, Person> map = findPerson.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        p -> p, 
        p -> p,
        Person::merge));
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way to do this without overriding equals and hashcode methods?

Comment: @user3378550 yes, change the first `p -> p` to `p -> Arrays.asList(p.getName(), p.getAge())` and change the type of the map to `Map<List<Object>, Person>`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer will be very similar to a recently-deleted answer:

```
findPerson = findPerson.stream()
                       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName,
                                Collectors.reducing((p1, p2) -> {
                                    p1.getAddress().addAll(p2.address);
                                    return p1;
                       }))).values().stream()
                           .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                           .map(Optional::get)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With Java 9, two of the lines at the bottom can be replaced with a single call to `Optional::stream`.

Using your example, the result is as follows:

```
[Person[bill, 31, [Address[666, uuu, hhh]]], Person[adam, 26, [Address[123, xyz, yyy], Address[456, rrr, kkk]]]]
```

**Note**: Remember to override `equals` and `hashCode` appropriately for `Person`.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to implement this without overriding equals and hashcode methods?